# Jasmine test removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I am trying to test the removeEventListener with jasmine. I have

```
describe('test', function(){
    'use strict';

    beforeEach(function() {
        affix('#test');

        method = {
            test: function() {
                console.log('hi!');
            }
        }

        spyOn(method, 'test');

        $selectedElement = $('#test');
        selectedElement = $selectedElement[0];
    });

    it('should remove event listener', function(){

        selectedElement.addEventListener('click', method.test);
        selectedElement.removeEventListener('click', method.test);
        $selectedElement.click();

        expect(methods.showLove).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

But this fails. Now I suppose this is because I have anonymous function here. Is there a way to remedy this without using non anonymous function?

If I put

```
function clickMe() {
    return 'bla';
}
```

and use that instead of `method.test` in the event listeners the test is successful. How to use the functions defined in the methods?

Is there a way to add or pass a reference to that anonymous function inside the object?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that jQuery trigger event wasn't working as it should, so I used the one on the [trigger events page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) on MDN.

This did the trick...